# jquery toggle an hover effect on click

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, attr

I have some problems in trying to toggle an attribute on click.

[here is the JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NSPUc/)

The hover effect works fine for me, but I want to toggle the effect when I click on a path (country)

Would be great if someone can help me.

This is what i try to get:

[Working example](http://gajel.de/map/)

Comment: i have no idea how i can do that, I am happy that get so far ;)

Comment: Really like the world map you have there :) Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

The click is identical to the hover:

```
$("path").click(function() {

    $(this).attr({
      fill: "#FF0000",
      stroke: "#00FF00"
    });
}) // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want :)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NSPUc/18/)

Comment: mayby my english is so bad that i dont could explain good enough, but your example just at an alter windowd onclick, but i want that the hover effect stay on a path when i click on it

Comment: i am really tired of being a JS noob :(

Comment: Oh, now I get what you want. W8 a sec

Comment: yex, but now teh hover effect doesn't work and i can select more than one path per click.

Comment: i load up an exmaple how ist should wordk maybe youd get ist than ;)

Comment: So you wnat the hover effect to stay on click?

Comment: YES exactly that is what i want ;)

Comment: Here it is :) use the $(this),data('clicked',true/false);

http://jsfiddle.net/NSPUc/18/

Comment: take a look at my first post, there is now and working exmaple what I want. the exmaple ist done with "jquery.maphilight.min.js". And i wasn't sure if "jquery.maphilight.min.js" also working with "path's" so i try it without "jquery.maphilight.min.js" ;)

Comment: The last example I gave you works, just change the code a bit and it will do what you want.

Comment: You are close. The only thing at yout last example is that its possible to click more than one path/country ;)

Comment: dude, just change the code a bit. Give an id to every country, on click check if any country was clicked if it was then disable the "clicked" style and apply that one to the clicked country instead.

Comment: ok i try it but i have much hope :D tank you very much for all that :)

Comment: Accept this as your answer so that other people searching for the same can see it

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
$("path").toggle(function() {
    $(this).attr({
        fill: "#FFFFFF",
        stroke: "#eee"
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).attr({
        fill: "#FF0000",
        stroke: "#00FF00"
    });
});
```

The code bellow will toggle from red to white and from white to red, so you can style according to what color do you want.
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NSPUc/7/)**

Comment: hm same thing here, ist doesn't toogle the hover effect wehen i click on a path :(

Comment: No? If you click it'll change the color to white again.

Comment: no it even turn red when i click on it. Just the hover effect workd like in my first example.